# Where can I find my home’s square footage?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

Pretty straightforward. I’d like to know what my homes exact listed square footage is, without having an appraiser come in and physically measure it or doing that myself. Is there a document from closing that would have this information? If so, which document? Is there a public record I can look up?

Additionally, my home includes a rooftop patio which is designed to be utilized (ie furnished, for the purposes of going up there to hang out). Is this area included when calculating/listing square footage?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "my home includes a rooftop"? Is this an area on the roof that you can go out onto?

Comment: Have you checked the documents you received when you bought the property? There may be full plans or perhaps a sketch plan with size markings.

Comment: Your purchase documents might include this data.  Another source might be your the county records office where you live such as the appraiser or comptroller (google for details).

Comment: @shoover yes my apologies. It is a rooftop patio that you can go out to

Comment: Usually, patios (whether on rooftop or ground, and whether covered or uncovered), unheated attics (even if carpeted and dry-walled), etc are not included in house square footage, but your locality might well use different rules.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am a bit confused, then, how a rooftop patio's added value could be accounted for with general estimation tools (zillow, Redfin). I feel as though this means I can only get accurate value assessment through a CMA?

Comment: Your question was about finding the square footage of your house, not about estimating what the house is worth, or will sell for. The latter has many other factors besides square footage, and what Zillow etc knows or uses in its estimates is not something I can comment on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to check with your city or county's Assessor's office.  Often this information is available online through their websites.  This official info is what your taxes are based on, so is probably the best "official" number for what your house square footage is.